Use importance sampling to post processing the posterior result of the MCMC chains
In one of the studies, I once found the following heuristics to perform the calibration,
Step 1: Running MCMC to get model parameters, with K chains
Step 2: Compute weight for these K chains, the weight is based on the likelihood based on the parameters corresponding to each chain
Step 3: The posterior prediction is then an ensemble prediction based on these K chains where the weight is computed in step 2.
It is more like an importance sampling approach.
Is this approach quite common in posterior prediction.

markov chain monte carlo methods are used to approximate integrals in a consistent way, ie, if you let the chains run for long enough, you will obtain a fairly accurate estimate of the integral. as far as i can tell from your description, the method you described voids the consistency guarantee. so i'm inclined to say no, this method you described is not common. however, can you provide a mathematical description of the method or provide a reference?

Two objections, at the very least:

Running (many) chains in parallel reflects on the distribution of the starting values as we cannot be sure to "reach" stationarity for all of them in a finite number of steps. Hence a bias.

Weighting MCMC values by their likelihood means the likelihood is counted twice (as a power of two!), since the values are approximately distributed from the posterior, i.e., the prior x the likelihood. (The harmonic mean approximation to the evidence is actually relying on this representation, by averaging the inverse likelihoods.) Hence another bias.


Now importance sampling may be associated with MCMC, as we recently demonstrated.
